# I am working on unit testing using sanctum. I was testing as acting as a admin using sanctum

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpunit, laravel-sanctum

I have make a unit test case as :

```
public function test_user_registration(){
         $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
         $this->withoutMiddleware();
         Bus::fake();
         $user = User::find(1);
         Sanctum::actingAs($user,['*']);
         $response = $this->post('/api/users',[
             "firstName"=>"Kamal",
             "lastName"=>"Garu",
             "email"=>"Kamasll@gmail.com",
             "roleId"=>[4],
             "defaultRoleId"=>4,
             "investorId"=>[15],
             "defaultInvestorId"=>15,
             "streetAddress"=>"Jalur Banj",
             "postalCode"=>"977",
             "city"=>"bhaktapur",
             "countryId"=>160,
             "phone"=>9741801138,
             "status"=>1,
             "emailPortfolioReport"=>0,
             "emailInvestorActivities"=>0,
             "emailMarketUpdate"=>1,
             "isdCodeId"=>149,
             "roleType"=>["investorInternational"]
         ]);
         VerifyUser::dispatch($response);
         Bus::assertDispatched(VerifyUser::class);
         $response->assertStatus(200);
     }
```

And everytime i run this code this throw error as "Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException: not authorized
"
Here 1 is the id of admin so m acting as a admin user. Need Help..

Comment: I think you still need to run middleware even when you do `actingAs` to initialise the guards

Comment: Can you confirm that the user is definitely getting loaded i.e. `dd($user);` after `User::find(1);`.

Comment: @Rwd Yes it does. I have used authorize method to create user and i what i found is i don't get currentAccessToken in testing whereas i got currentAccessToken when running through postman.

Comment: How are you performing the authorization check?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `$this->withoutMiddleware();` bit?

Comment: @Rwd I have used this code :  $this->authorize('viewAny', User::class); before user create.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I did but don't work..

Comment: `$this->authorize('viewAny', User::class);` is usually for the `index` method. Please can you add the code for your `UsersController` and if you're using them the FormRequest and Policy for User as well.